# KMeans implementation in OpenCV 2

Tags: opencv, k-means

I am trying to implement kmeans in OpenCV 2.3.1 to find the centers of clusters. I have a color thresholded, binary image stored in convertedImg and want to find the coordinates of the centers of each of the four clusters.

kmeans(convertedImg, 4, labels, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0), 10, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);

I am not sure how to get the coordinates of the centers from the OutputArray centers, which appears to be a Mat that is 4 x 320. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution pointed out here, you can get the centroids by averaging the instances clustered into each group.

[OpenCV K-Means (kmeans2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650904/opencv-k-means-kmeans2)